# Mobile application

Tags: app

3 years ago I invented an idea about creating special mobile application. However, I could not patent it due to high cost of. I participated in diffirent conferences and competitions with my idea to obtain funding for the last 2 years. However, several weeks  ago, one huge US company got patent on exactly this idea. I am from Uzbekistan, though I have an evidence about my idea and participation in different programs with it, the application is only on idea stage. Can I claim on any IP issues? and what alse can be done?

Comment: Did they get a *patent*, or just file an application? I know you said they got a patent, but the answer would be easier if it's the latter, so I just wanted to double-check.

Comment: The company I mentioned about is Facebook, and they got a patent.

Comment: Chances are, if they actually were granted a patent recently, it had been filed over two+ years ago. That information is available free online.

Comment: Yep, like jimm101 said, it's probably worth checking the filing date of that patent and ensuring that you publicly disclosed it before that date. If you didn't, there's not much you can do. But if you did, it might be worth speaking to a patent attorney to review options.

Answer (score 2):

If you can document that you presented the patented claims in public prior to the filing by the patent holder, your presentations can be used as prior art to invalidate their patent. This will likely require litigation. One of their competitors may offer compensation for your efforts.

If you have presented the material in any public forum you can no longer rightfully  obtain an EU patent. If you presented over a year ago, you cannot rightfully obtain a US patent. But, by invalidating theirs, you will be free to market your own product without infringing on their rights.